# Table issue in karate v1

Tags: karate

After upgrade to karate v1.0.1, table data type has an issue, here is my scenario and error returned:

```
Scenario: table test
* table table1 =
| column |
| 'row1' |
| 'row2' |
* print table1
```

---

```
* print table1
>>>> js failed:
01: karate.log('[print]',table1)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "table1" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

I downgraded to v0.9.6 to check and this issue did not occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=` symbol is not required.

```
* table table1
| column |
| 'row1' |
| 'row2' |
* print table1
```

You are welcome to update the docs via an open-source PR.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt help! I see this is already updated in the docs, I must have missed it.